# Using Tabcontrol in MVVM pattern in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have multiple window files and i want to merge my Xaml files(window) into a Tab control in a MVVM Pattern.
Each item Tab will represents a Xaml file.
i need something like this:

```
 <TabControl >
        <TabItem>
            <local:FirstView></local:FirstView>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem>
            <local:SecondView></local:SecondView>
        </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

but i get this Error:

"Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual."

I have seen many topics like this but they use user control or they use a single view with multiple View Model.

Is there any way to import window(xaml) into tab control?

And another important thing, i want to have a button like Cancel, Pushing Cancel means we have to go back one level(go to another tab Item).
view model is not aware of view, so how can i navigate through them?

Comment: Most probably, some of your views are windows. They should be usercontrols

Comment: As to the "cancel" problem I usually have the main view implement an "INavigation" interface that is then injected into the child view models.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET would you please explain it more?

Comment: @Farshad sounds like a different question; or you can bring it up in the WPF chat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to import window(xaml) into tab control?

No, there isn't. A `System.Windows.Window` cannot be a child of another `System.Windows.Window`.

The contents of the tab items should be defined as `UserControls`.

You should just be able to move the contents of your windows to the user controls.

Comment: So you mean Creating user Control is the only way?

Comment: Yes. A window *cannot* be a child of a TabItem.